# R: how to print out the bad line number during parsing

Tags: r, fixed-width

I have a fixed width file that I am reading in this way:

```
library(readr)
mydata <- read.fwf(file="myfile.txt", widths = c(12, 7, etc))
```

It returns:

```
Error in substring(x, first, last) : 
  invalid multibyte string at '<cd>S    '
```

As the file is pretty big I would like to find out what is the line number in the file that returns the error. How can I get that using R?

Comment: try `mydata <- read.fwf(file="myfile.txt", widths = c(12, 7, etc), fileEncoding="latin1")`? Try searching on the error `invalid multibyte string` as there are lots of other SO questions relating to this

Comment: thank you. It fixed the issue using ```latin1``` as encoding so I can parse the whole file. However I am still wondering if there is a way to get the line number that creates the problem.